# How to restart amount value from 0 at midnight every day?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know exactly how to run this function correctly. I'm using `localstorage` that it stores the amount value forever and I want it to be 0 for each day at 00:00:00 when a user gets more than 0 in `Earned Today` tag. My code and  `localstorage`  work fine, where the value will automatically set to 0 as long as the page is open, but when it is closed and open it the value remains the same and does not change after midnight.
I prefer `jQuery` code if it's possible and thanks so much for helping me.

```js
//$("#earnedToday").text(localStorage.getItem("TodayEarning"));
let amount = 0;
$("button").click(function(){
let updateEarning = parseFloat($("#earnedToday").text());
 amount = updateEarning;
 amount += 0.01;
 $("#earnedToday").text(amount.toFixed(2));
 let earning = parseFloat($("#earnedToday").text());
 //localStorage.setItem("TodayEarning", earning);
  
});

function setToZeroAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
var now = new Date(), then = new Date();
then.setHours(hours, minutes, seconds, 0);
if(then.getTime() < now.getTime()) {
    then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
}
var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#earnedToday").text(0); 
  let earning = parseFloat($("#earnedToday").text());
 //localStorage.setItem("TodayEarning", earning);
},timeout);

}
setToZeroAt(0,0,0);
```

```css
.box{
      width: 25%;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    }

    #earnedToday{
      color: #02b4e4;
     
    }
    button{
    margin-top: 20px;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
      <p>Earned today</p>
      <p id="earnedToday">0</p>
    </div>
    <button>Earn</button>
```

Comment: `0.38` is stored in localStorage - just confirming ? and you want this value to be 0 each at midnight ? Well it depend how are you saving it the first place. Can you share all the relevant code.

Comment: You can't do "every day" unless the user has the page open continuously.  Try storing the date as well and check if the date has changed - if it has, store the new date and set the earnings value to 0.

Comment: ATD has the right answer here. Just store the date that the score was recorded, and if the date changes then clear the score. Be aware though that it can be "cheated" by changing the device's clock so if you need it to be "secure" then you need a server to provide a "trusted" time source.

Comment: it can be cheated anyway by typing `localStorage.setItem("TodayEarning", 99999999999999)` in console

Comment: Without knowing what the entire page may do, we can't really say whether or not cheating could be an issue.  If the page is being submitted with just the value of "TodayEarning", then there's no form of checking possible - the user could just keep clicking the Earn button and who's to say if the resulting TodayEarning figure is correct?  I have assumed that this is just a cutdown version of the page and the functionality provided with the question is merely to work out how to reset the value to 0 for each new day - and, therefore, this figure is just for display purposes only.

Comment: You can run setInterval for 30 mins or so and check if it is midnight or close to midnight and change the localstorage value. But the problem is you can change it exactly + it wont gets updated for all user anyway when you use localstorage. So it is not ideal to store it in localstorage. Or you can set with the last changed time and when the time as passed the midnight you can update it based on the logic.

Comment: I guess that my code doesn't look good or I'm missing something I haven't added. BTW after updating my code, so, the user will be rewarded every hour he clicks the button, I didn't write the countdown timer code. So, I want when user gets some certain amount for example: 0.34 I want this value to be 0 for each midnight. My code and  `localstorage`  work fine, where the value will automatically set to 0 as long as the page is open, but when it is closed and open it the value remains the same and does not change after midnight. So, is it possible to do this using `localhost`?